# strange java.lang.NullPointerException at onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Who can help me with this strange error?
I marked the line when I get the error.
Thanks

```
         /************************************************
         *      setItemsAsReadTask
         ************************************************/

        private class SetItemsAsReadTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<FeedItem>, Void, Void> {

            @Override
              protected void onPreExecute() {
                //AGGIORNO LISTVIEW SUBSCRIPTIONS

                }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<FeedItem> ... articoli) {
                if(this.isCancelled()==false){
                    if(articoli.length!=0){
                ArrayList<FeedItem> segnaComeLetti = articoli[0];
                reader.setMultipleNewsAsRead(segnaComeLetti);
                    }
                }
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                //TODO TRUE O FALSE
                if(this.isCancelled()==false){
                    Log.d(TAG, "chiedo aggiornamento updateUI");
                    mCallbacks.onSubscriptionsUpdated();
                }<---- that's the line of the error
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (Callbacks)activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}
```

Comment: mCallbacks is probably not initialized.

Comment: The line where there is nothing but a right curly bracket?

Comment: what does your Logcat say?

Comment: have you tried if and what onSubscriptioonsUpdated is returning!?

Comment: Little off-topic: replace `this.isCancelled()==false` by `!this.isCancelled()`. You'll get the same result but the second one is the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mCallbacks` variable is probably null. Use defensive programming and check for `null` before calling the method. Also, instead of checking if a boolean value is false, just use the not `!` logical operator.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    if (!this.isCancelled()){
        Log.d(TAG, "chiedo aggiornamento updateUI");
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onSubscriptionsUpdated();
        }
    }
}
```